# Wamp is online but localhost keeps loading

Tags: apache-http-server, wamp

I installed Wamp 2.4 in my system, but it is not loading localhost. It keeps loading and loading in Firefox. In Apache errors log, I found the following error:

```
[Sat Nov 30 20:11:44.232540 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 2592:tid 1508] 
(OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. :
AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt as Administrator

Run

> netsh winsock reset

Reboot if necessary or just restart Apache

Try loading localhost again.